# Javascript dynamic ALTER sql getting erred

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is the error message I get. Not sure what's missing

> Execution error in stored procedure COMPARE_UPDATE_METADATA_BETWEEN_STAGES: SQL compilation
>
> Error: syntax error line 1 at position 104 unexpected ' V'. At Statement.execute,
>
> line 30 position 66

Actual dynamic SQL query I retrieve using `.getSqlText()`

```
"ALTER TABLE DEV2.SCHEMANAME.TBLNAME ADD COLUMN FAC_ID NUMBER(38,10); "
```

It works fine when I execute the SQL manually.

```
    create or replace procedure Compare_Update_Metadata_Between_STAGES(
        SRC_DBNAME string,
        SRC_SCHEMANAME string,
        TRGT_DBNAME string,
        TRGT_SCHEMANAME string,
        TBLNAME string
    ) returns variant
    language javascript as $$

                  var stage_table_control = " SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) AS COL_NAME, UPPER(DATA_TYPE) AS DATA_TYP, "
                    stage_table_control += "       CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'TEXT' THEN 'VARCHAR(' || CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR) || ')' "
                    stage_table_control += "           WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('TIMESTAMP_NTZ', 'DATE', 'TIMESTAMP_LTZ','TIMESTAMP_TZ') THEN DATA_TYPE || '(' || CAST(DATETIME_PRECISION AS VARCHAR) || ')' "
                    stage_table_control += "           WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('NUMBER', 'FLOAT') THEN 'NUMBER('||CAST(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR) || ',' || CAST(NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX AS VARCHAR) || ')' "
                    stage_table_control += "           WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('BOOLEAN','VARIANT','BINARY') THEN DATA_TYPE  END AS CHAR_LEN "

                    stage_table_control += "  FROM DEV.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS "
                    stage_table_control += "  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = " + String.fromCharCode(39)  + SRC_SCHEMANAME + String.fromCharCode(39)
                    stage_table_control += "   AND TABLE_CATALOG   = " + String.fromCharCode(39)  +  SRC_DBNAME + String.fromCharCode(39)
                    stage_table_control += "   AND TABLE_NAME   = " + String.fromCharCode(39)  +  TBLNAME + String.fromCharCode(39)
                   stage_table_control += "   AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN " + " ( SELECT UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) FROM DEV2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "  + String.fromCharCode(39)  + TRGT_SCHEMANAME + String.fromCharCode(39)
                    stage_table_control += "   AND TABLE_NAME   = " + String.fromCharCode(39)  +  TBLNAME + String.fromCharCode(39) + ")"

                    var stage_sql_statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: stage_table_control});
                    var stage_resultSet = stage_sql_statement.execute();
                    var stage_column_name_array = "";               

                     while (stage_resultSet.next()) {
                          var stage_column_name = stage_resultSet.getColumnValue(1);
                          var stage_data_type = stage_resultSet.getColumnValue(2);
                          var stage_char_len = stage_resultSet.getColumnValue(3);

                          var alterSQL =  "ALTER TABLE " + TRGT_DBNAME + "."  + TRGT_SCHEMANAME + "." + TBLNAME + " ADD COLUMN " + stage_column_name + String.fromCharCode(160) + stage_char_len + ";"
                              var sql_statement1 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: alterSQL});
                              var resultSet1 = sql_statement1.execute();
                            //  var resultSet1 = sql_statement1.getSqlText();
                             //alterSQL = "";            

                    }

        return alterSQL;
    $$
```

// + " " + //this is what causing an error i believe in below alter

statement

```
        var alterSQL =  "ALTER TABLE " + TRGT_DBNAME + "."  + 
        TRGT_SCHEMANAME + "." + TBLNAME + " ADD COLUMN " + 
        stage_column_name + " " + stage_char_len + 
        ";"
```

Comment: Why are you inserting and ascii code 160 into your ALTER string?

Comment: Because i wanted insert space and snowflake doesn't like when i did + " " + -- this erred so i used ascii code. Do you think that's the problem? Here is the syntax i was trying, i was trying to get to                                                                                       
ALTER TABLE  dbName.SchemaName.TableName Add Column Colname varchar(100);

Comment: The ascii code for a space is 32, not 160: https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @NickW that resolved the issue. 160 was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message and lack of actual argument(they were replaced by placeholders:

> error: syntax error line 1 at position 104 unexpected ' V'. At Statement.execute,

It is possible that the name contains space in identifier that was not properly enclosed with `""`.

One possible place of such occurence is:

```
stage_table_control += "  FROM DEV.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS "
stage_table_control += "  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = " + String.fromCharCode(39)  + SRC_SCHEMANAME + String.fromCharCode(39)
```

Instead of concatenating SQL String(which is prone to SQL-Injection attack) parameter binding should be preferred:

```
stage_table_control += "  FROM DEV.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS "
stage_table_control += "  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = :1 "
stage_table_control += "   AND TABLE_CATALOG = :2 "
// ...

var stage_sql_statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: stage_table_control
                          , binds: [SRC_SCHEMANAME , SRC_DBNAME , ...]});
```

Comment: problem with ALTER Table script, i was able to execute first sql successfully.

Comment: @user1810575 Still it could be rewritten to much easier form. As for alter: `+ String.fromCharCode(160)` usage of non-braking space is probably causing the issue

Comment: That's how i started but when i used + snowflake erred on me. Can you re-do the alter statement and re-send so that i can see what's wrong.

Comment: // + " " + //this is what causing an error i believe in below alter 
statement
            var alterSQL =  "ALTER TABLE " + TRGT_DBNAME + "."  + 
            TRGT_SCHEMANAME + "." + TBLNAME + " ADD COLUMN " + 
            stage_column_name + " " + stage_char_len + 
            ";"

Comment: @user1810575 WHere is the data type used? `...ADD COLUMN + stage_column_name + " " + stage_data_type  + "(" + stage_char_len + ")"`